# Gulp & Elixir - watching ts files and then rebundling

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp

I am using elixir with gulp and angular 2 with typescript. I want to be able to watch any .ts files and the run this elixir function anytime something changes, so it rebundles automatically.

Snippet

```
elixir.extend('compile_angular2', function(src, output) {

    new task('compile_angular2', function() {

        return gulp.src(['./angular2/main.ts'])
            .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
            .pipe(concat('angular2.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'));
        });

});
```

Comment: What is the question here? Also, Are you sure you tagged this question with the right Elixir? You have it tagged with Elixir the programming language.

Comment: I have removed [tag:elixir], since it is a tag for Elixir the programming language.